# Can I construct the name of a Powershell environment variable?

Tags: powershell

I would like to dynamically construct the name of an environment variable. I tried this:

```
$partition = $env:partition
$desiredvariable = "abc_$partition"
$desiredvalue = $env:$desiredvariable
```

This doesn't seem to work. Can this be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

### Yes you can!

Environment variables can be manipulated using the [`[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.setenvironmentvariable(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
$SomeName = "test"
[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable($SomeName,"value")
```

You can then access it like normally:

```
PS C:\> $env:test
value
```

Or, using the [`GetEnvironmentVariable()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getenvironmentvariable(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
PS C:\> [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable($SomeName)
value
PS C:\> [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("test")
value
```

Answer (score 2):

You were close.

```
$t='tmp'
dir env:$t
```

Output:

Name                           Value
----                           -----                                                                                                                                      TMP                            C:\Users\ESDADMMS\AppData\Local\Temp